# Yandex Map API. Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromGlobalPixels' of undefined

Tags: yandex-maps-api, polyline

В определенном порядке действий получаю ошибку. Добавляю polyline в GeoObjectCollection. Вешаю на него {GeoObject}.editor.startEditing(). После этого мышью меняю положение bounds (Чтобы Polyline был вне). Удаляю Polyline {GeoObjectCollection}.remove({GeoObject}); И при последующем изменения положения bounds сразу после события boundschange получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromGlobalPixels' of undefined
    at a._calculatePixelGeometry (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js...)
    at a._updatePixelGeometry (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
    at a._onVertexChange (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
    at a._onMapBoundsChange (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
    at r._callListeners (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
    at r.fire (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
    at r.fire (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
    at J._onActionChange (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
    at s._callListeners (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
    at s.fire (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.74/combine.js?...)
```

Причем данная ошибка появляется только при редактируемой polyline. Добавление stopPolyline в любой момент времени - не помогает.

Comment: Соберите пример на jsfiddle, где будет воспроизводиться проблема.

Comment: В общем ошибка как оказалось возникает только у polyline в форме геодезических кривых при редактировании https://jsfiddle.net/uws3befL/ Т.е. если не редактировать кривую или убрать "geodesic":true, то ошибки не возникнет.

Comment: На примере - кликните по одной из линий и перетащите карту пару раз чтобы 2 раза отработало событие boundschange.